# db2set DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I want to disable all compatibility features by resetting the DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR registry variable, so i used following command:

db2set DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=

db2stop

db2start

but it is not effected to regester variable.

Therefore I edit the DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR dirrectly bu regedit admin role, but when I restart computer, the setted value back to default value (MYS).

Please give me any suggestion if you had same problem.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Try `db2set DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=NULL` -- note the uppercase NULL. Existing databases will not be affected, of course.

Comment: Thank you very much!

So if i created any database, then i have to drop that database to take the effect of this command?

Comment: For a clean start -- yes, you'd want to re-create the database while the desired DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR setting is in effect. I'm not very familiar with the MySQL compatibility behaviour, I'm assuming most of it is manifested at runtime, but there likely are some database objects that are only created for the compatibility mode.

Comment: I used DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=NULL but the error message appear, it mean null is an invalid argument, please suggest me if you have  another solution. Thank you verry much!

Comment: Finally i found the answer, i edited the register variable dirrectly. Thank you so much!